# How do I read the state of 3 output pins on an Arduino UNO and then NAND them together?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

So I am working on software to control a H8 inverter. I got code that does SPWM for a 3 phase inverter online. I then applied a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO and this is the result I got:
[image: Result of applying a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

and this:
[image: Result of applying a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

I used a hardware NAND gate and I got this:
[image: Result of applying a hardware NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

```
//-------www<electronics-project-hub>com--------//
#include <math.h>
int Output1 = 11;
int Output2 = 10;
int Output3 = 9;

int Output4 = 8;

uint8_t a = 0;
uint8_t w = 0;  //PB3
uint8_t x = 0;   //PB2
uint8_t y = 0;  //PB1
uint8_t z = 0;  //PB0

int potVal = 0;
float A = 0;
float B = 0.104;
int Freq_IN = A0;
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;
int var3 = 0;
int var4 = 0;
int var5 = 0;
int var6 = 0;
float Phase1 = 2 * PI / 3;
float Phase2 = 4 * PI / 3;
float Phase3 = 2 * PI;
boolean toggle = true; // true = Enabling Serial Plotter Output
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Output1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Output2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Output3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Freq_IN, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  A += B;
  analogWrite(Output1, var1);
  analogWrite(Output2, var2);
  analogWrite(Output3, var3);

  //digitalWrite(Output4,! 
(digitalRead(Output1)&&digitalRead(Output2)&&digitalRead(Output3)));

   /*g1 = (PORTD & B00100000) >> 5;
    g3 = (PORTB & B00000100) >> 2;
    g5 = (PORTD & B00001000) >> 3;
    g7 = ~((g1&g3)&g5);
    digitalWrite(G7,g7);*/
    /*
    g4 = (PORTD & B01000000) >> 6;
    g6 = (PORTB & B00000010) >> 1;
    g2 = (PORTB & B00001000) >> 3;
    g8 = !((g4&&g6)&&g2);
    digitalWrite(G7,g8);*/
  a = PORTB & 0b00001111;
  w = (a & 0b00001000) >> PORTB3;
  x = (a & 0b00000100) >> PORTB2;
  y = (a & 0b00000010) >> PORTB1;
  z = ~(w&x&y&z);
  PORTB = PORTB | z;
  if (toggle == true)
  {
    Serial.print(var1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(var2);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(var3);
  }
  var4 = 126 * sin(A + Phase1);
  var1 = var4 + 128;
  var5 = 126 * sin(A + Phase2);
  var2 = var5 + 128;
  var6 = 126 * sin(A + Phase3);
  var3 = var6 + 128;
  if (A >= 2 * PI)
  {
    A = 0;
  }
  potVal = analogRead(Freq_IN);
  delay(potVal);
}
//-------www<electronics-project-hub>com--------//
```

I would like to point out that the software NAND output stayed ON all the time. The hardware NAND output varied, which is the result I am trying to get.

Comment: The inputs for your hardware NAND and your software NAND are completely different. Of course you won't have the same results. Your software NAND inputs are never all high at the same time.

Comment: I get worried when I see `&&` applied to bits.  Also, those slow and bloated `DigitalRead()` calls do NOT happen at the same time.  You know that, right?  And using `AnalogWrite` on pins that you'll use `DigitalRead` on is a really bad idea.  This is a very, very bad design.

Comment: @TomServo so what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic, your code should be good:

```
digitalWrite(Output4, !(digitalRead(Output1) && digitalRead(Output2) && digitalRead(Output3)));
```

Or

```
digitalWrite(Output4, (!digitalRead(Output1) || !digitalRead(Output2) || !digitalRead(Output3)));
```

Maybe the problem comes from the fact that you are using the `analogWrite` function and the `digitalRead` on the same pin. Or the simulation tools is not working properlly (I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

Create another pin for reading the (NAND) all together

Answer (score 0):

Another question here is do you want to combine all the signal like interference I don't think using NAND would make that possible maybe you should try using another function